# Execution of method even after return is executed in java

Tags: java, function, methods

Here is my code(method):

```
    int temp =0;
    result=false;
    isPossible(temp);
    if(result) System.out.println("YES");
    else System.out.println("NO");
}} private static void isPossible( int i) {
    if(i>n || i+m >= n || i==n-1){
        result =true;
        return; 
    }
    if(visitedArray[i] == true){
        System.out.println(A[i]+"d");
        return;
    }
    visitedArray[i]= true;
    if (i+1 < n && A[i+1]==0){
        System.out.println(A[i]+"a");
        isPossible(i+1);            
    }
    if (i-1>=0 && A[i-1]==0){
        System.out.println(A[i]+"b");
    isPossible(i-1);
    }
    if(A[i+m]==0 && i+m < n){
     System.out.println(A[i]+"c");
        isPossible(i+m);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
0c 0b 0a 0d 0c YES
```

I want to know why does the last if loop get executed even after the return is executed, i.e. why does the output print '0c' even after '0d' i.e. return was executed?

Comment: time to grab a good debugger and go through the stack frames to see what it's doing

Comment: Can you post the code that calls this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing is that in the cases that you are printing a or b you call the `isPossible` method again, but you do not do return. there for the flow of the program can be:

1. first loop - prints C and enters the second loop
2. second loop - prints B and enters the third loop (notice - loop #2 is not done)
3. third loop - prints A and enters the fourth loop (notice - loop #3 is not done)
4. fourth loop - prints D, returns
5. Now we're back to the continue of loop three, which can print C again and recurse one more time

Don't know where the `YES` printing is coming from, does not appear in your posted code, but you get the idea

Comment: What will happen to loop #2,will it also recuse one more time like loop #3(5th point)?

Comment: @VisheshSharma - yes, it will

Comment: So the order after it prints D will be, loop #3 ,then loop #2 will get executed,right?